# Android library modules gradle

Tags: android, gradle, module, android-gradle-plugin

I'm making my own library on Android Studio and I would like to split my library with "modules".

For example I would have a module to show video, an other to show pdf an other to show image etc...

When I build my library I would like to have choice to chose which module I'll have. For example for an app I will use SDK with only video, and another app with image and pdf. And have a main file that will be there for every build.

I heard about product flavors but I'm only able to create build variants, Can I have only debug and release build but build just some "module"?

Now I'm trying with sourceset

```
def modules = getDirNames("src/modules")
def full = Arrays.asList("video", "pdf, "image")
def video = Arrays.asList("video")

modules.retainAll(video)
sourceSets {
    modules.each({ module ->
        "${module.capitalize()}" {
            //manifest.srcFile "src/modules/${module}/AndroidManifest.xml"
            main.java.srcDirs += ["src/modules/${module}/java"]
            //res.srcDirs = ["src/modules/${module}/res"]
            //assets.srcDirs = ["src/modules/${module}/assets"]
            //jniLibs.srcDir "src/modules/${module}/libs"
            //jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
    })
}
```

I've created a folder modules and video where I've set a manifest and java folders

Does someone know something about it, am I wrong?
A good tutorial?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show code. There are errors? Show them.

Comment: Im at very beginning, i'm trying to understand how it works. I've added productflavors in gradle file with 2 versions and a dimensionflavors that's all

Comment: With sourceSets and main.java.srcDirs += ["src/modules/${module}/java"] it seems to work so i can add or remove my package for each build I need. Is it well done like this or could I do better ?